# Como hacer la validacion y filtrado

Tags: python, mvc, odoo

En el popup que esto yeditando añadí un filtro ma que busca por tipo de cotización por empleado y por destino osea que hace las 3 consulta a la vez pero en este caso debería de arrojarme información respectiva al registro que cumpla las condiciones que estoy hacendó pero al aparecer el reporte me lo esta mandando vacio asi como no esta entrando a la función que puse para hacer dicho filtrado

Adjunto codigo:

```
import json
import io
from datetime import date
from odoo.tools import date_utils
from odoo import fields, models, api
from odoo.exceptions import UserError, ValidationError
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
class SaleReportAdvance(models.TransientModel):
_name = "sale_report_general"

from_date = fields.Date(string="Fecha de inicio")
to_date = fields.Date(string='Fecha final')
type_transport = fields.Selection(
    [('c', 'Cotizaciones'), ('a', 'Aereo'), ('m', 'Maritmo'), ('t', 'Terrestre'), ('f', 'Ferias'),
     ('i', 'Importacion')], string='Tipo de cotizacion', default='c', required=True)
seller_id = fields.Many2many(comodel_name='hr.employee', string='Ejecutivo')
country_arrival = fields.Many2many(comodel_name='res.country', string='Destino')

def _get_data(self):
    sale = self.env['sale.order'].search([('state', '!=', 'cancel')])
    validity_date = date.today()

    if self.from_date and self.to_date:
        sales_order = list(filter(lambda
                                      x: x.date_order.date() >= self.from_date and x.date_order.date() <= self.to_date,
                                  sale))
    elif not self.from_date and not self.to_date:
        sales_order = list(filter(lambda
                                      x: x.date_order.date() <= validity_date,
                                  sale))
    else:
        sales_order = sale

    result = []
    seller = []
    country = []
    for rec in self.seller_id:
        a = {
            'id': rec,
            'name': rec.name
        }
        seller.append(a)
        logger.info('**********seller*** {0}****'.format(seller))
    for rec in self.country_arrival:
        a = {
            'id': rec,
            'name': rec.name
        }
        country.append(a)
        logger.info('**********country*** {0}****'.format(country))

    logger.info('***********************Eligio ver algun tipo de cotización*************%s******' % self.type_transport)


   logger.info('***********************Eligio ver el informe con los tres filtros tipo ejecutivo y destino*************%s******' % self.type_transport)
    if self.type_transport == 'c' and self.seller_id and self.country_arrival:
      for rec in seller and country:
         for so in sales_order:
           if so.seller_id != rec['id'] or so.country_arrival == rec['id'] and so.date_order:
            res={
              'name': so.name,
              'date': so.date_order,
              'partner': so.partner_id.name,
              'consignee': so.consignee_id.name,
              'freight': so.freight_type,
              'gross': so.gross_weight,
              'volume': so.volume,
              'invoice': so.invoice_amount,
              'types': so.type_transport
            }
            result.append(res)
            logger.info('**********Esta viendo todas las cotizaciones de un empleado y destino ***{0}****'.format(res))

data = {
        'ids': self,
        'model': 'sale_report_general',
        'form': result,
        'seller_id': seller,
        'country_arrival': country,
        'no_value': False,
        'employee': self.seller_id.name,
        'country': self.country_arrival.name,
        'from_date': self.from_date,
        'to_date': self.to_date,
        'types': self.type_transport
    }
    return data
def get_ventas_report(self):
    data = self._get_data()
    logger.info('**************Obtuvo el informe de ventas')
    return self.env.ref('sale_report_terrestre.action_general_report').report_action(self, data=data)

    if self.date_order and self.validity_date and not self.seller_id and not self.country_arrival:
        data['no_value'] = True
        return data
```

asi es como tengo estructurado el codigo bueno en si es mas codigo pero solo comparto la parte que tengo el problema porque es mucho codigo la verdad estoy algo confundido ya que me esoty dando cuenta que solo puede hacer dos validaciones la mismo timepo y no 3 o que ppuedo hacer o como tendria que poner la decision para que funcione ya que si en el segundo if quito alguno y solo dejo 2 condiciones si funciona y ya no funciona con las 3 y si necesito que funcione con las 3 que puedo hacer aqui para corregir ese error

pd olvide poner como tal el error el erro esta en que no hace la busqueda cuando pongo un destino que si exista en algun registro y pero el empleado no y por si ambos existen en los registros tambien manda el pdf vacio